# Docker run command not working in Ubuntu 20.04 after latest docker update

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I followed the below command to setup docker in Ubuntu 20.04.3

`$ sudo apt-get update`  
`$ sudo apt-get install docker.io`

then tried to run hello-world image  
`$ sudo docker run hello-world`

Got following error  
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally  
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world  
2db29710123e: Pull complete
Digest: sha------   
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest  
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "error adding seccomp filter rule for syscall clone3: permission denied": unknown.  
ERRO[0008] error waiting for container: context canceled

`$ docker -v`  
`Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2`

Need help to get rid of this issue. Previously I was on ubuntu 18.04 with a lower version of the version of docker and took an update given by the community and lead to this error. Then updated OS (20.04.3) thinking that it might solve this issue but with no success.

Comment: You might want to take a look at: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/6203

Comment: Thanks. But that won't work  I already went through that thread and they are suggesting to downgrade the docker version which is not available anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `docker.io` but use the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) way to install `docker` on ubuntu. On Ubuntu I usually run the following to install `docker`:

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable" && \
apt-cache policy docker-ce && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have to go with docker.io only for some official reason

Comment: Another possibility about the `docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim` is that it has to do with your architecture for see both https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15354 and https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-failed-to-create-shim-oci-runtime-create-failed/187771